# boostrap for background video which is not embedded

Tags: jquery, html, css, mobile

how do I add a bootstrap for a background video which is not embedded?

The text on my screen is messed up with the video on a mobile device. Please help

```
<section id="video">
<video autoplay loop class="video"> 
<source src="ink.mp4" type="video/mp4"> 
</video>
</section>// this is video part I want to bootstrap 
<section id="meat"> 
<P> <span class="name"> xxxxxx</span>
<br/>
<span class="surname"> xxxxxxx</span>
</P> 
 </section>
```

// this is the text which goes in the video. I can bootstrap the text but unable to do background video.

Comment: Can you provide the code you have so far and maybe a screenshot of the issue?

Comment: <section id="video">
 <video autoplay loop class="video">

        <source src="ink.mp4" type="video/mp4">
        </video>
    </section>/// this is video part I want to bootstrap
    <section id="meat">
        <P>
          <span class="name">  xxxxxx</span>
            <br/>
          <span class="surname"> xxxxxxx</span>
            </P>
    </section>// this is the text which goes in the video..I can boostrap the text but unable to do background video.